# MySQL query with alphanumeric order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, alphanumeric

I'm trying to get a list of some products' model & all models are alphanumeric.

I tried

```
ORDER BY CAST(field_name AS UNSIGNED)
```

and

```
ORDER BY field_name + 0
```

and

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(field_name)
```

and some other ways.

They works for most of them but there are some values that doesn't match the order.

The result I get is like

EAG-75

EAG-110

...

ESCG-500

ESCG-600

...

EYG-40

EYG-55

...

EMG-440

**EMG-20**

**EMG-27**

...

**EAG-100**

...

I don't understand what is causing this.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you want them sorted? give an example. If you order alphabetically, EAG-110 comes before EAG-75

Comment: I want them to be sorted alphanumericcaly like EAG-75 , EAG-100 , EAG-110 , EMG-20...

Comment: @Onur: I think you actually means "per non-numeric prefix, sort numerically"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to sort the 2 bits separately if you want a correct numeric sort per non-numeric prefix

```
ORDER BY
    -- sort by prefix only
    LEFT(MyCol, INSTR(col, '-')-1),  
    -- sort numerically within prefix
    CAST(SUBSTRING(MyCol, INSTR(col, '-')+1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: As long as all your model numbers are in the format AAA-##, you won't get much better than this solution.

Comment: Hi, it works perfect in that format but if there are some other results like AAAA# in the same query, then it doesn't work well for 4 character results, how can I fix it? thanks in advance

Comment: oh I think I fixed it by changing -1 to -2 in LEFT(MyCol, INSTR(col, '-')-1)

Answer (score 0):

Would `ORDER BY LENGTH(field_name), field_name` work better for you?